# A general setting to state the isomorphism theorems for (complete) (semi)lattices

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, lattice-orders

Lattices, complete lattices and (complete) lower and upper semilattices are all very similar algebraic structures. The homomorphisms between lattices of the same type and also the Isomorphism Theorems hold for all of these structures, but it would be clumsy to write the same statement for each of these classes separately.

I would like to know if there is a general setting for which each of these classes of lattices are particular examples. Universal algebra seems like the way to go; however, most texts that I have found make no mention of how to view a complete (semi)lattice as an algebra in the sense of universal algebra, and I am unsure whether it is possible at all since arbitrary meets and joins do not constitute finitary operations.

Is there a way to achieve this general setting? Some references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you make more precise, which statements you want to prove? I would say, that in the sense of universal algebra these things are structures with one relation symbol and existence of meets / joins is achieved by a set of logical formulas you impose. You have a notion of congruence relation for such structures and you have to check which congruences give quotients in your desired category.

Comment: Just the isomorphism theorem, really, which I know has a general version in universal algebra (that for an algebra homomorphism $f:A\to B$, one always has that $X/\ker f \cong im f$). Could you please elaborate on how to impose these logical formulas? My issue with universal algebra is that I do not know how to express "arbitrary meets/joins" in the precise manner that universal algebra requires.

Comment: It depends on your definition of lattice (as a partial order or as a structure with meet and join operation?). Then it depends on your notion of homomorphism between lattices. There is no general definition of kernel. The general thing you can mod out is an equivalence relation satisfying certain compatibilities (congruence relation). For complete lattices you need infinitary operations to make the algebraic approach work and I think this is not feasible. So I advise to work with a congruence relation on a poset.

Comment: An order-theoretic lattice $(X,\leq)$ is a poset, such that each two elements have a meet and a join. In a complete lattice you have arbitrary meets and joins. By "formulas" I mean, that you add these requirements without changing structure. Are you familiar with this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems ? Since lattices can be defined by operations the section "Universal algebra" applies to lattices. I'm not sure which theorem you actually want to prove about complete lattices, since you have not written down a statement, so I'm not going deeper here.